# Free app to detect & delete duplicate files from my Mac

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, file

I am just wondering is there any way to find duplicate files on my Mac?

**For example:** when I download something from bittorrent, some unnecessary files also download along with the main file with `.dat` extension. I want to delete all of these `.dat` files at one time. Currently I have a lot of these files on my computer & they are stored in many different directories. It would be a lot of work to delete them one by one.

Thus, are there any free apps to do that sort of job or some way I can find & delete them?

Comment: Do you want to find & delete duplicates or files ending in `.dat`? This doesn't seem to be the same thing.

Comment: @patrix Thanks for commenting. No, here i just gave an example with that. I want to find out all duplicate files what ever that is then delete.

Comment: Your so called "example" is confusing and is not really an example of what you're asking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beware : once you change the content of a torrent, **you're not able to seed it anymore.**

Open a finder window, search for all files named `.dat` then just press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (select all) then <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> (delete) then <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>+<kbd>maj</kbd> (empty the bin)

You can also use [gemini](http://macpaw.com/gemini) to find duplicates then delete them with Finder, or if you're familiar with bash :

```
find -not -empty -type f -printf "%s\n" |
    sort -rn |
    uniq -d |
    xargs -I{} -n1 find -type f -size {}c -print0 |
        xargs -0 md5sum |
        sort |
        uniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate
```

Comment: Running on 10.13.6 I get `find: illegal option -- n` (OS X has a BSD `find` not GNU) and `uniq: illegal option -- w`. Also the path doesn't seem to be specified. To use the GNU `find` it needs to be installed: `brew install findutils`. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277917/97255) to [Find not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277914/97255)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [Gemini](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gemini-the-duplicate-finder/id463541543?mt=12). Its $10US, but it is a very powerful utility. I've used it with iTunes music folders and numerous folders of camera card dumps. A colleague of mine uses Gemini to prune through 15 years of digital files, many of which were duped as backups when technologies changed at my school. (Disclosure: I have no financial interest in the Gemini app.)